# n-tier design, lookup tables, and custom entities

Tags: asp.net, architecture, n-tier-architecture

In an n-tiered application where you are using custom entities, how do you find yourself handling data needed from lookup tables?  Do you create entities for each of these lookup tables or employ some other strategy?

For example.  I have a "Ratings" lookup table that will be used to populate a dropdownlist.  Would you create a ratings object with a ratingid and rating property and pass that to your UI or is there a more efficient way to go about it?

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: "What I am looking for specifically is your strategies for mapping an existing lookup table in the database back up to the UI level. Lets assume we already have a set of lookup tables." - please edit the question to be specific about what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that the solution will depend on how often the lookup data changes, whether or not it needs to be editable, and whether or not you're enforcing referential integrity at the database.  I think it makes the schema more understandable if you put each lookup type into a separate table.

I generally don't create entities for each lookup table, but instead will load most of the common lookups into structures that are easily re-used by the application - for an asp.net app, for example, I'll create hashtables or ordered dictionaries which can easily be bound to most web controls.

And, horror of horrors, I sometimes create a singleton to manage access to all these lookups, which can be stored as static vars or in the cache, depending on requirements.

Answer (score 0):

We seperate out the different look up types into different objects.  It seems to be a little more work up front, but it provides us the ability to make changes to each individual object when we need to, such as an addition of additional information to an object.